# Flutter SVG as ImageIcon

Tags: flutter, dart

My designer has switched from PNG to SVG files, 'cause our icons are to pixelated.

How I can use a **SVG** as an **ImageIcon**?.

Previous I have used this for PNG files:

```
ImageIcon(AssetImage('assets/images/ic_home.png')
```

I'm using `flutter_svg` (`SvgPicture.asset(item.icon, height: 24, width: 24)`)

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You actually can't do it as [mentioned here](https://github.com/dnfield/flutter_svg/issues/152#issuecomment-575976530) by Flutter SVG creator that `PictureProvider` and `ImageProvider` are incompatible and `ImageIcon` needs an `ImageProvider`.

However, you don't actually need to do it, and you probably won't as well. You can refactor your code to use:

```
SvgPicture.asset(item.icon, height: 24, width: 24)
```

And nothing else. That should be enough, no need for more complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and the link. How is your code example different with mine?

Comment: It isn't. I'm just explaining you exactly that you should keep it that way.

Comment: The Problem is I need to tint the icon after creating. (TabBar). For that I need an Icon.

Comment: You can wrap your `SvgPicture` with a `ColorFiltered` widget for that.

Comment: How will ColorFiltered help? I can also change the color of the SVG direclty (```SvgPicture.asset(item.icon, height: 24, width: 24, color: Colors.grey)
```). I'm searching some way to do it direclty with TabBar.
```TabBar( labelColor: AppColors.green, unselectedLabelColor: AppColors.greyDark,);```

Comment: You can tint your child widget with it.

Comment: I solved the problem with rebuilding widget when tabcontroller index has changed.  

```    _tabColorListener = () {
      if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) setState(() {});
    };```

``` for (int i = 0; i < navigationItems.length; i++) {
      tabs.add(SizedBox(
        height: kBottomNavigationBarHeight,
        child: Tab(
          icon: SvgPicture.asset(navigationItems[i].icon, height: 24, width: 24, color: i == _tabController.index ? AppColors.green : AppColors.greyDark),
        ),
      ));
    }```

Thanks a lot for your help and ideas @Miguel Ruivo